# async function don't return value in right order

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get user data from firestore, but functions don't behave as I want.
When I run the init function I got a response in the console like: *" in init", "after", "null", "user is active"*, but I want to receive a response like: *"user is active", "in init", user data instead null," after"*;

I know it is probably simple, but I am sitting all day on this problem.
What should I do to get data in this order?

```
init()

async function init () {
     await userIsActive()
    console.log("in init");     
  await getDaySpending();
    console.log("after") */
    
}

function userIsActive(){
    firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user=>{
    if(user){
      console.log("user is active");
      return true
    }else{
      console.log("no user");
      return false
    }
  })
  }

 function getDaySpending(period = '7-2020') {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
     console.log(user)    //I got null instead user data
    if(!user) return;      
    const uid = user.uid;
    const snap  = await  firebase.firestore().collection(uid).doc(period).get();
    if(snap.exists) {
      return snap.data().spending;
    } else {
      // handle the case where there was no data
    }
  }
```

Comment: There is no "null" log in the code, did you mean "no user" ?

Comment: I delated accidentally log. Yes I got null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the userIsActive function. You can't return a value from within an enclosed function.

```
// This function returns undefined
function asd() {
  (() => { return 1; })();
}
```

In this case, assuming you are using the firebase api correctly which I am not familiar with, you would need to use an explicit promise.

```
function userIsActive(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user=>{
    if(user){
      console.log("user is active");
      return resolve(true)
    } else{
      console.log("no user");
      return resolve(false);
    }
 })
}
```

I suspect this is not the proper way to use this api though so hopefully someone more knowledgeable on the topic can chime in.

Comment: You are welcome. Please flag as answered.

Answer (score 0):

`init` function is `async` if no `await` is present the execution is not paused and your code will then be executed in a non-blocking manner. Add keyword `await`.

Mozilla docs:

> An async function can contain an await expression, that pauses the
> execution of the async function and waits for the passed Promise's
> resolution, and then resumes the async function's execution and
> returns the resolved value.

Comment: Where should I put await keyword ? Can you correct my function ?

Comment: Where you call it. `await init()`

Comment: When I add await before init(), i got error: Unexpected reserved word

Comment: That is because you are calling it in not async function but in main file. Try this:

(async function() {
  await init();
})();

However it looks like the issue was a different one :) Glad you got it working.